# Como atualizar um <h:form> de 30 em 30 segundos JAVA WEB

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf, java-ee

Estou tentando criar um painel mostrando o resultado dos vendedores em um telão na minha empresa.

preciso temporizar o painel de 30 em 30 segundos para que os resultados estejam sempre atualizados.

não tenho ideia de como fazer, toda ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Está usando algum framework tipo primefaces ou rich faces?

Comment: Estou usando Primefaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso Brother?

```
<h:form id="formulario">
    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{bean.atualizaForm}" update="formulario" />
    ...

</h:form>
```

Comment: To testando aqui, mas já vi que vai dar certo! Muito obrigado!